# Python - Group categories

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, grouping

I have 56 categories of data that sometimes occur together and other times do not. I quantified this using the conditional probability of having data in category A given that I have data in category B (P(A|B)) and created a 56x56 matrix of these probabilities. I want to combine these categories into groups that are likely to occur together; however, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

I tried making a cut-off of co-occurring 95% and grouping by these by sorting on whether data co-occurs; however, the results do not look completely finished to me.

Is there a way to perform the grouping on the probabilities or better perform the binned grouping task shown below?

```
import pandas as pd, seaborn as sns

df2.head(10)
sns.heatmap(df2)

for _ in range(100):
    df2 = df2.reindex(index=df2.sort_values(df2.index.to_list(), ascending=False).index.to_list())
    df2 = df2[df2.sort_values(df2.columns.to_list()).columns.to_list()]

sns.heatmap(df2)
```

[image: data]

[image: before sorting]

[image: after sorting]

Comment: Sounds like a union-find / connected component problem: your graph has 56 nodes, an edge from A to B if P(A|B) > .95. Should be easy with `nx`

Comment: I assumed all chances are equally weighted? Can we use Laplace criterion to the find posteriori prob?

Comment: @QuangHoang - is `nx` a python module? I'm googling it and coming up with an app creation framework

Comment: @CeliusStingher - all chances of each category? No, some appear with a probability of 0.86 and others with a probability of 1E-4

Comment: It's [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html)